# Denominator for "operator /"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is there a way to overload `operator/()` to use the class as the denominator?

Like so:
`int foo = 5 / object;`

Comment: This excellent SO post on [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) includes good information about implementing binary arithmetic operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a free function:

```
int operator/ (const int, const MyClass &);
```

If it needs to access private members that you have no interface for, make it a friend inside your class as well:

```
friend int operator/ (const int, const MyClass &);
```

Comment: What exactly is a free function? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @Dasaru, One that's not enclosed in a class. In this case, it being a member function constrains it to take a `MyClass *` as the first argument, leaving one open. The order of arguments corresponds to the way you call it, so it's impossible to switch them if it's in the class.

Comment: @Dasaru: You'll also see them called `non-member` functions.

Answer (score 3):

Use a free function instead of a member function for `operator/`.

Binary operators typically have the same operand types. Assuming that `foo` has a non-explicit constructor taking an `int`, you would have:

```
struct foo
{
  foo(int i) {};
};

int operator/(foo const& x, foo const& y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Free function is your friend:

```
int operator/ (int, const MyClass &);
```

Comment: Where friend does not mean `friend` ;-).

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin: Not necessarily -- but `friend` might come into use here too.